# Could not find installable ISAM. While Uploading Excel File (.xls) Format

Tags: asp.net

Please help me with this code .I  Am Downloading a file with xls Extension and  uploading the same file Gives me (Could not find installable ISAM) Error .

I have tried With Almost everyConnection string but Still was not able to debug this error

if (FileExtension == "xls")
                    {
                        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + ServerFullPath + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0 Xml";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ServerFullPath + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
                    }

[image]
The error Comes while opeing the connection i.e (oledbconn.open())

Comment: When I changed _Extended Properties=Excel 8.0 Xml_ for _Extended Properties=Excel 8.0_ without the Xml, it worked for me

Comment: But mine code is Giving this error 
External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: External table is not in the expected format

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

string filepath = "C:\upload\abc.xls";

string Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";